# How to trigger WooCommerce user profile edit change?

Tags: plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I have a WooCommerce installed wordpress theme and I developed a custom plugin. The custom plugin stores the users information. If a user edit their account details from fronted then I want to reflect this change in my custom plugin. So here which hook is used to trigger this change? please provide your valuable answers.

Comment: I am also facing same issue. any best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code

```
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_user_profile_update' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_user_profile_update' );

function save_user_profile_update( $user_id ) {

    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'address', $_POST['address'] );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'city', $_POST['city'] );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'postalcode', $_POST['postalcode'] );
}
```

Comment: it is not working for me